# How to simultaneously play two PCM audio streams in one DMA

Tags: audio, stream, stm32, dma

I am working on a project on the stm32f769i-disco board, which has to run a video game made by me. The graphical part is solved, where I have problems is when I need to play two or more wav files, I do not know which is the correct way to add them in a single stream.

What is the algorithm that I must follow for more than one stream?

PD: I know manage a single stream which is played through dma with double buffer.